# Serialization based on model attributes

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, system.reflection

I am making a .NET 6 project, and I need to accomplish a task against an external API.

Let's define a model to set up the context.

```
class MyModel
{
    public bool field1;
    public string field2;
}
```

So, that model will be used in two actions.
First, a GET request, that can NOT contain some of the fields above, and
a POST request, that also can NOT contain some of the fields above.

For example:

```
// GET
{
    MyModel: {
        field1: true
    }
}

// POST
{
    MyModel: {
        field1: false,
        field2: "some value"
    }
}
```

So, when I perform a GET operation, I want to include some particular fields. And send it two another external API, so I read from API1, and send it to API2.

When I perform a POST operation, I read from API2, and insert data into API1, but I just want to include some predefined fields.

My desire it's to create a custom attribute to reflect that behaviour:

```
class MyModel
{
    [Read, Write]
    public bool field1;
    [Write]
    public string field2;
}
```

Also note that a field can be used also for the GET operation, althought for the POST operation.

I am getting lost in how to implement the behaviour of the `Newtonsoft.Json` package to make it understand how to deserialize and serialize those specific fields based on an input operation.

My first approach it's to define a `Read` and `Write` interfaces, and when a request for write is made to the external service, it will serialize the fields that has a `Read` annotation to send the data, and when a request is made for read, the model will know how to deserialize the content into the attributes that has a `Write`.

As you may notice, concepts are inverted. `Read` means send data to the external API (because it will be read from another but internal API of the project), and `Write` means read data from the external API (because will be inserted in our internal API).

Thanks.

Comment: to have better seperations of concerns its better to create 2 models. one GET and one for POST. then you will not have the mess of applying attributes

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm)?

Comment: Build two models. You'll thank me later.

Comment: @MindSwipe that's exactly what I am looking for. Exactly means, in the abstract idea. Still loss in the impl with the custom attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to simply go for two models.

A `Read` Model

```
class MyReadModel
{
    public bool field1;
}
```

And a `Write` Model

```
class MyWriteModel
{
    public bool field1;
    public string field2;
}
```

This makes it very clear.

Think of other situations: E.g. you want to generate a API Documentation with Swagger. You would also have to deal with your custom attributes.

In you controller you will have to methods:

```
[YourAllowAttribute]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyReadModel>> Get()
{
    // stuff
}

[YourPostAttribute]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyReadModel>> Write()
{
    // stuff
}
```

Security trimming can be achieved by implementing two attributes or policies e.g. `[YourAllowAttribute]` or `[YourPostAttribute]`.

With this approach you will not mix concerns in your model.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for your detailed response.
I've already implemented a quite similar logic and it's working perfectly fine.

This post it's about learning, let's call it... `deep C#`. It's not about of making a good practices REST api, it's just about to find a way of doing things to just know about them in practice, not only by read docs. 

Hope this explain my situation.